# Geocoder API: XSD scheme version 6.2: SearchResponseViewType contains SearchResponseViewType in stead of SearchResultsViewType

Tags: xsd, here-api

I'm trying to generate the data types for Go used in the Geocoder API.

The types should be defined in the XSD scheme, which can be found here: https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/xsd/LBSP-Search-Search.xsd

But, when I start comparing the xsd-scheme to the documentation, the xsd doesn't seem to be correct.

Documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html

The documentation gives me this structure:

```
"Response" of type SearchResponseType
 - "MetaInfo" of type SearchResponseMetaInfoType
 - "View"     of type SearchResultsViewType
    - "ViewID"
    - "PerformedSearch"
    - "Results" of type SearchResultType
```

The XSD scheme on the other hand gives me this:

```
"Response" of type SearchResponseType
 - "MetaInfo" of type SearchResponseMetaInfoType
 - "View"     of type SearchResponseViewType
    - "ViewId" of type int
    - "Label"  of type string
```

If I'm correct, the `View` in `SearchResponseType` should be a `SearchResultsViewType`. The `SearchResultsViewType` is defined in the XSD scheme but never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SearchResponseViewType` in the XSD is an `abstract` type and therefore cannot be used directly in the response XML. The `SearchResultsViewType` is derived from the `SearchResponseViewType` abstract type. So that is why you see `SearchResultsViewType` instead of `SearchResponseViewType` in the documentation.